# global variables are undefined in typescript coming from webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, typescript2.0

In `typescript 2.4.0` I am trying to create global/environment variables using `DefinePlugin` using `webpack`.  So here is the approach I am trying to take:

webpack.js Define part

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   environment: JSON.stringify('DEVELOPMENT'),
}),
```

globals.ts

```
declare const environment: String;
console.log(environment);
export { environment };
console.log(environment);
```

environmentService.ts

```
import { IEnvironment } from 'environment';
import { environment } from '../globals';
console.log(environment);

export default class EnvironmentService implements IEnvironment  {
  environmentName: String = environment;

  get isDevelopment(): boolean {
    return this.environmentName === 'DEVELOPMENT';
  }

  get isProduction(): boolean {
    return this.environmentName === 'PRODUCTION';
  }
}
```

In the console log I get:

```
DEVELOPMENT
DEVELOPMENT
undefined
```

So `console.log(environment);` inside `environmentService.ts` is giving me `undefined` when I am expecting `DEVELOPMENT` and I am not sure why?

It appears it only `exports` the variable and not the value?

If someone can explain what I am doing wrong and why its getting `undefined` i would appreciate it.

**Edit 1**

I think I see what `DefinePlugin` is doing.  Its not setting `environment` to `DEVELOPMENT` but rather replacing lines `console.log(environment);` with `console.log('DEVELOPMENT');` and when it `exports` `environment` its undefined.

Comment: Where does `environment` or `environmentName` get defined?

Comment: In global.ts and DefinePlugin is replacing the value.

Comment: Where does it replace the value? You're importing `DefinePlugin` as `IEnvironment`, but you never use it... unless my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DefinePlugin inlines code parts, thats why you need all those `JSON.stringify('DEVELOPMENT')` not just `'DEVELOPMENT'`. It replaces global identifiers it knows with the given code parts as is. If you define `environment: '"PROD" + "DUCTION"'`

Then

```
if(environment === 'PRODUCTION') {

}
```

Becomes

```
if("PROD" + "DUCTION" === 'PRODUCTION') {

}
```

Something like this should work in ts2

```
const env: String = environment;
export { env as environment };
```

Comment: Now I get `Cannot find name 'environment`.

Comment: @Michael Which line?

Comment: Got it to work.  I took out `declare const environment: String;` so when I put it back in it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can create a `@types` folder and put a declaration file `global.d.ts` in it, with just below content.

```js
declare const environment: string;
```

TypeScript includes all `@types` packages by default during compilation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Comment: Yes, `declare const environment: string` removes the TS warning. use :string instead of :String

Answer (score 4):

You need update your globals.ts like this for any webpack DefinePlugin variables:

```
declare const environment: string;
const _environment = environment
export { _environment as environment };
```

[More here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/37).